# Remove old values in list and add new ones

Tags: c++, qt, list, queue

I'm really not sure how to explain this properly, but let me try.  I have a C++ program that is listening to data on a CAN bus (communication bus for vehicles).  Every 1 second, I receive a new message off the bus that contains diagnostic information about error messages.  The message is not fixed length, so the message one time may contain 5 faults, and the next time it may contain 3 faults.  The message comes from two (or more) different sources, each one of them sends it every 1 second.  In my UI, I need to display the list of active faults by cycling through them at a rate of 1 per every 5 seconds.

Here's my question.  How do I efficiently keep a list updated with the latest information?  Adding to the list is no problem, but how do I remove an item that should no longer be in the list?  In other words, if I only receive 3 faults in the message, that means that 2 of them do not exist anymore.  The only thing that I can come up with is using timestamps and a bunch of for loops to compare the 2 messages and add/remove/update the list.  Is there something more efficient that already exists for this sort of thing?

EDIT:  To clarify, I need to remove items from the list because those faults are no longer active.  If I have an array as follows:

```
// Message that is received: (psudo code)
Fault newFaults1[5] { Fault1, Fault2, Fault3, Fault4, Fault5 };
Fault newFaults2[7] { Fault1, Fault2, Fault3, Fault4, Fault5, Fault6, Fault7 };

// Populate the array that holds both array values
for (int i = 0; i  < newFaults1.Count(); i++)
    Faults[i] = newFaults1[i];

for (int i = 0; i < newFaults2.Count(); i++)
    Faults[i + newFaults1.Count()] = newFaults2[i];

// Now, the next time a message is received, there are fewer faults.
Fault newFaults1[2] { Fault1, Fault2 };
Fault newFaults2[1] { Fault1 };

// TODO: How do I remove all of the old items in the Faults array?
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem but I don't understand the criteria for removing an item from the list. Your explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: If a message is added and then removed quickly (within 5 seconds), should it still be displayed at least once?

Comment: Indeed, the criteria are not clear. Also, you say 2 of them do not exist anymore; is that because the list contained 5 items when you received the new ones?

Comment: @john: I edited my question to add more detail.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @ilent2: No, it does not need to be displayed if it happens that quick. Also, I updated my question to clarify some things.

Comment: @KurtPattyn: I updated my question to clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think question might be a lot simpler than it first appeared. Your question seems to be about how to resize an array?

The simple answer is not to use an array but a `std::vector` instead. E.g.

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<Fault> faults;

// add a fault to vector
faults.push_back(f);

// remove all faults from vector
faults.clear();

// resize the faults vector
faults.resize(2);

// get size of vector
num = faults.size();

// loop through all faults
for (i = 0; i < faults.size(); ++i)
{
    f = faults[i];
    // do something with f
}
```

Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not very clear. If the new faults you receive, represent the current state, then you can just clear the old array, and push the new faults into them, like:

```
onNewFaultsReceived(Faults *faults) {
    clear old Faults array;
    insert faults into Faults array
```